# "Energy" of a signal

Tags: integration, signal-processing

If we have a signal

$$x(t)=\begin{cases} t &0\leq t < 1 \\ 0.5+0.5\cos(2 \pi t) &1 \leq t < 2 \\ 3-t &2\leq t<3 \\ 0 &\text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

It's energy is $E(x)=\frac{25}{24}\approx 1.0417$. Calculate energy for $y(t)=\frac 13 x(2t)$

I did my work like this, does it seem correct?

$$E=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|y(t)|^2 dt$$
now
$$x(2t)=\begin{cases} 2t &0\leq 2t < 1 \\ 0.5+0.5\cos(4 \pi t) &1 \leq 2t < 2 \\ 3-2t &2\leq 2t <3 \\ 0 &\text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$
then

$$|y(t)|^2=\frac 19 \times\begin{cases} 4t^2 &0\leq 2t < 1 \\ (0.5+0.5\cos(4 \pi t))^2 &1 \leq 2t < 2 \\ (3-2t)^2 &2\leq 2t <3 \\ 0 &\text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

So the integral would be
$$E=\frac 19 \big( \overbrace{\int_0^{1/2} 4t^2 dt}^{A_1} + \overbrace{\int_{1/2}^1 \frac 14+ \frac 12 \cos (4\pi t)+\frac 14 \cos^2 (4 \pi t)dt}^{A_2}+\overbrace{\int_1^{3/2} 9-12t+4t^2 dt}^{A_3}\big)$$

\begin{align} A_1&=\int_0^{1/2} 4t^2 dt = \frac 16 \\ A_2&=\int_{1/2}^1 \frac 14+ \frac 12 \cos (4\pi t)+\frac 14 \cos^2 (4 \pi t)dt \\ &=\int_{1/2}^1 \frac 14+ \frac 12 \cos (4\pi t) +\frac 18 \cos(8 \pi t) + \frac 18 dt =\frac {3}{16} \\
A_3&=\int_1^{3/2} 9-12t+4t^2 dt = \frac{1}{6} \end{align}
So the energy is $E=\frac 19 (A_1+A_2+A_3)=\frac{25}{432} \neq \frac {1}{18} E(x)$. Did I mess up the integral?

Comment: hey have you defined the function y properly since $y(t)=\frac{x(2t)}3$ so for $ 0 \le 2t \le 1$ y=2t and so on

Comment: do you mean the $|3-2t|$ when $t \in [2,3]$?

Comment: Your definition given for $x(2t)$ is incorrect.

Comment: Oh damn. Care to explain how? I'm genuinely not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: patience is the virtue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function y is

$2t$ for $0\le 2t <1$

$\frac{1+cos(4\pi t)}2$ for $1\le2t<2$

$3-2t$ for $2\le2t<3$

and $0$ elsewhere

Comment: Okey. How does this affect the integral? The limits are multiplied by $\frac 12$ because the $2t$. So $2t \to t\in[0,0.5], \frac{1+\cos{8\pi t}}{2} \to t \in [0.5,1]$ and so on?

Comment: yes since its 2t that lies in between the intervals but not t

Comment: Well I corrected the mistake, but I still get the wrong result from the integral.

Comment: $\frac {25}{432}=\frac 1{18}E(x)$

Comment: $\frac {25}{432}=\frac 1{18}E(x)$  got it @ELEC

Comment: Oh hah! Stupid me..

Answer (score 2):

If you call energy the squared $\ell^2$ norm, then 
$$E[y]=\int|y(t)|^2\mathrm dt=\frac19\int|x(2t)|^2 \mathrm dt=\frac19\int|x(u)|^2\frac{\mathrm du}2=\frac1{18}E[x].$$